# Does my daughter need consent from both parents?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I currently live in Canada with my wife. I had applied for a visitors visa for my 11 year old daughter, who lives in Egypt, about a month ago. I was sent a letter online by CIC today stating that a parental authorization letter is needed for her to travel. I have already given them one from her mother when i first applied.

Does this mean they also want one from me ?

Comment: You're applying for a visa for your daughter to go _where_? Does she currently live with you in Canada?

Comment: (But yes, children are often expected to have explicit permission to travel from _both_ their parents, where the parents have joint custody. The underlying concern that one party in a failing relationship/marriage might unilaterally take the child to a different country where later custody decisions by the home country's courts would be difficult or impossible to enforce).

Comment: @HenningMakholm  She lives in Egypt. I applied for a visitors visa about a month ago. I provided a consent letter from her mother since she’s in her mothers care. Today they sent me a letter stating that they need a parental consent letter in order to continue processing the application. Does that mean they also need one from me?

Comment: Yes, they need a separate letter from you for exactly the reason stated by Henning Makholm.

Comment: @Traveller why is that a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @Traveller want to convert to an answer?

Answer (score 3):

The documents a minor child needs to enter Canada depend on whether the child is travelling alone or with someone. Authorisation from both parents is required if the child is travelling alone.

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/minor-children-travelling-canada.html

If a minor child is traveling alone, or will be accompanied by an adult not the child's parent, the documents they should present are:

- their own passport
- a copy of their birth certificate, and
- a letter of authorization, in English or French if possible, and signed by both parents or by their legal guardian which lists:

  - the parents’ (or legal guardian’s) address and telephone number, and
  - the name, address and telephone number of the adult who will look after the child in Canada.